# What is the meaning of overbased additive in lubricants?

Tags: organic-chemistry

From the google search that I did, I do not understand what overbased means.

Any comment,link or answer would be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In detergents, by overbasing, it is meant that a stoichiometric excess of the metal be present over that required to neutralize the anion of the salt. The excess metal from overbasing has the effect of neutralizing acids which may build up in the lubricant. A second advantage is that the overbased salt increases the dynamic coefficient of friction. Preferably, the excess metal will be present over that which is required to neutralize the acids.

Comment: Very likely the same for lube oils. They are to neutralize carbonic acid ,etc , in combustion gases that may leak past the rings. I remember reading of Mg and Ba being used.